# Adding a service connection in ARCGIS PRO

Tags: arcmap, web-service, proxy

I am using ARCGIS PRO 2.8.0. I am tring to add a new ARCGIS server connection:
I got this URL:
https://v5.gis-net.co.il/proxy/proxy.ashx?http://arcgis005/arcgis/rest/services/Herzliya/herzliya_main_date1/MapServer/
But when I add it, I get an error massage that it can't connect to the server.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does that link even work in a browser outside of ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: the proxy server only permits the authorised URL or application , so you will not be able to connect to it using your ip.

Comment: @bixb0012 it works in a browser. That is why I don't understand why it is not working in the Arcgis

Comment: @Mapperz so is there any other way to connect to it?

Comment: it is possible, but most likely illegal, you might need to reach out to the company/government running the arcgis server.